# HTML5 <audio> Hiding the audio source

Tags: php, apache, html

I'd like to be to use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag to stream mp3 files from my website. The problem is, any ol' Joe can view the page source and see the location of the streaming mp3 file, then they'd be able to download the whole file directly (as opposed to 'streaming' via the player).

Is there **anything** I can do to keep the user from being able to view the location of the mp3 files on my server? What options do I (or don't I) have?

I'm using Apache with PHP, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use a php script to pull the audio file for you. set the source to a php script rather than the actual file. Then in the php script you could do checks to make sure the request is valid before returning the mp3 file.

Comment: What would a PHP script that returns a file (as opposed to HTML) look like?

Comment: You'd just need to set the headers content type eg: `header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');` and content length eg: `header('Content-length: ' . filesize($yourMp3));` before pushing the contents of the MP3 file.

Comment: that's exactly right, you could go one step further and store the mp3s outside the webroot too.